# Categories in listview androidstudio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm new on Android. How can I make categories in my ListView with an arrow on the categories. For example I want to see 100 categories and after I click on some categories I can see inside

Comment: check my answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249781/load-data-into-an-expandablelistview/37250461?noredirect=1#comment62031374_37250461

Answer (score 0):

In Android with ExpandableListView you can create listviews with categories.

There are plenty of tutorials and sample are availabe to do it.

following are the few good links:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html
http://javapapers.com/android/android-expandable-listview/
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

For understanding the concept and theory have a look on official developer page
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html